# Не появляется внешняя консоль при запуске консольного приложения в MonoDevelop

Tags: c#, monodevelop

Пытаюсь запустить проект со стандартным кодом

```
using System;

namespace Console1
{
class MainClass
{
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write ("Hello World!");
    }
}
}
```

В Свойствах проекта поставил галочки "Запустить во внешней консоли".
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Нажимаю "Start Without Debugging" и внешняя консоль не появляется!

Версия MonoDevelop 5.7. ОС Mageia 5 x64

Comment: Не появляется, или просто слишком быстро исчезает? попробуйте добавить `Console.ReadLine();`, чтобы ваше приложение не выходило сразу же после вывода строки.

Comment: Попробовал Console.ReadLine();. Внешней консоли все равно не наблюдается. Только "Вывод приложения" появляется при запуске, он вместо консоли и работать можно, но все равно странно что внешняя консоль не появляется.